# PHP Unable to display all required data from Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to create a nicely working e-commerce website.
However, when I try to view the created orders.
The ones that are already in the database and only the first record in the specific order is displayed.

Thank you for your help.

Code:

```
<html>

<?php
# Access session.
session_start() ;

# Redirect if not logged in.
if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ] ) ) { 
    require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ; load() ; 
}

# Set page title and display header section.
$page_title = 'currento' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;

# Open database connection
require ('../connect_db.php');

$uid = $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ];
#Returns all the records from the orders table
$query = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE user_id = '$uid' ";
$result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $query ) ;    

# Display body section.
echo '<body>';

#If the variable result contains rows...
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 )
{

    #Display the page header
    echo'<header> <h1> Your orders </h1> </header>';

    #Main content displayed in a table, TR stands for Table Row
    #Main content displayed in a table, TR stands for Table Row
    echo '<table border ="1"><tr>';

    #Column Headers
    echo '<td> <strong>Order ID</strong><br> </td>'. 
         '<td> <strong> User_ID    </strong><br> </td>'. 
         '<td> <strong> Total Cost </strong><br> </td>'.
         '<td> <strong> Dispatched? </strong><br> </td>'.
         '<td> <strong> Order Date </strong><br> </td> </tr>';

     #Returns a more detailed view of a single item in the database.
     while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
     {
        #TD stands for Table Data and adds a cell to the Table Row
        #The full stop is used as concatenation (to join two strings)
        echo '<td> <strong>' . $row['order_id'] .'</strong><br> </td>'. 
             '<td> <strong>' . $row['user_id'] .'</strong><br> </td>'. 
             '<td> <strong>' . $row['total'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
             '<td> <strong>' . $row['Sent'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
             '<td> <strong>' . $row['order_date'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
             '<td><table>';


        $oid = $row['order_id'];
        $Contents_Query = "SELECT * FROM order_contents WHERE order_id = '$oid' ";
        $Contents_result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $Contents_Query) ;   

        while ( $content_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $Contents_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
        {
            #TD stands for Table Data and adds a cell to the Table Row
            #The full stop is used as concatenation (to join two strings)
            #echo '<tr><td> <strong>' . $content_row['item_id'] .'</strong><br> </td>'. 
            # '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['quantity'] .'</strong><br> </td> </tr>';
            $iid =  $content_row['item_id'];
            $Contents_Query = "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE item_id = '$iid' ";
            $Contents_result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $Contents_Query) ;   

            echo '<td> <strong>Item ID</strong><br> </td>'. 
             '<td> <strong> Item Name </strong><br> </td></tr>';

            while ( $content_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $Contents_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
            {
                #TD stands for Table Data and adds a cell to the Table Row
                #The full stop is used as concatenation (to join two strings)
                echo '<tr><td> <strong>' . $content_row['item_id'] .'</strong><br> </td>'. 
                     '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['item_name'] .'</strong><br> </td> </tr>';              


            } 

            #    '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['total'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
            #    '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['Sent'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
            #    '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['order_date'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
            #    '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        #Ends the table row.
        echo '</tr>';

     }
     echo '</table>';

     # Close database connection.
     mysqli_close( $dbc ) ; 
}
else 
{ 
    echo '<p>There are currently no items in order_contents.</p>' ; 
}

// This is order contents
include('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Screenshot of how the table looks
[image]

Comment: you're probably outputting before header; what does error reporting say and `mysqli_error($dbc)` on the queries?

Comment: btw; your acceptance record is questionable. Any of those past questions solved? If so, it'd be best to mark them as solved.

Comment: No errors are shown.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You are re-using `$Contents_result` inside a loop that already uses it. That will destroy the outer loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are re-using `$Contents_result` inside a loop that already uses it. That will destroy the outer loop.

```
    $oid = $row['order_id'];
    $Contents_Query = "SELECT * FROM order_contents WHERE order_id = '$oid' ";
    $Contents_result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $Contents_Query) ;   

    while ( $content_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $Contents_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC ))
    {
        #TD stands for Table Data and adds a cell to the Table Row
        #The full stop is used as concatenation (to join two strings)
        #echo '<tr><td> <strong>' . $content_row['item_id'] .'</strong><br> </td>'. 
        # '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['quantity'] .'</strong><br> </td> </tr>';
        $iid =  $content_row['item_id'];
        $Contents_Query = "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE item_id = '$iid' ";
        $Contents_result2 = mysqli_query( $dbc, $Contents_Query) ;   
// error correction     ^
        echo '<td> <strong>Item ID</strong><br> </td>'. 
         '<td> <strong> Item Name </strong><br> </td></tr>';

        while ( $content_row = mysqli_fetch_array( $Contents_result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC )) {
// error correction  --------------------------------------------- ^
            #TD stands for Table Data and adds a cell to the Table Row
            #The full stop is used as concatenation (to join two strings)
            echo '<tr><td> <strong>' . $content_row['item_id'] .'</strong><br> </td>'. 
                 '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['item_name'] .'</strong><br> </td> </tr>';              


        } 

        #    '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['total'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
        #    '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['Sent'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
        #    '<td> <strong>' . $content_row['order_date'] .'</strong><br> </td>'.
        #    '</tr>';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now as I wanted it to. Thanks again :)